# switch-case with preg_match (+ starts with / strpos)

Tags: php, regex

I wanna accomplish something like this:

```
!say some message
```

which then is taken to a function, which proceeds with the content. As you can imagine, I'm listening on some text-inputs. Right now I'm facing the problem, that strings like this also trigger the `case`:

```
this is !say some text
```

**Code:**

```
$prefix = "!";
switch ($message->content) {
    case preg_match("/[^.*]$prefix . 'say' (.*) /", $message->content):
    _say($message);
    break;
}

function _say($message)
{
    $parts = explode("!say", $message->content);
    return $message->channel->sendMessage(trim($parts[1]), true);
}
```

From my understanding, the regexp is correct (also confirmed on a [regexp-tester](http://www.phpliveregex.com/)).

Tested with `substr` as well, but that doesn't do it either.

```
case substr($message->content, 0, 3) == $prefix . 'say' :
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The question rather is, have you tested the output of your function calls? You're assuming`$message->content` is by default correct. Debugging is the key to programming.

Comment: well, it does say the correct part, so everything after `!say`, but regardless of the position in a string

Comment: Perhaps you should use `substr($message->content, 0, 3) == $prefix . 'say'` instead of `preg_match()`. This also means, perhaps for longer commands that your `switch` statement should be changed. However... you could make it a substring as far as the first `strpos()` of `{space}`

Comment: tried that as well, but it seems like I'm losing the important part. I'll update the question with that code you suggested

Comment: I've updated the code on the already accepted answer. The new code is more clean and you should use it as a basis.

Comment: will do, thanks for the improvement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134138/discussion-between-xorifelse-and-dassaffe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command is a command, it should not be something to be fooled around with. So instead of using regex I suggest a simple string comparison:

```
$prefix = "!";

function _say($message){
    return $message->channel->sendMessage(trim($message), true);
}


if($message->content[0] == $prefix){
  if($p = strpos($message->content, ' ') !== false){
    $cmd = substr($message->content, 1, $p);

    switch($cmd){
      case 'say':
        _say(substr($message->content, $p));
        break;
      default:
        die('unknown command');
    }

  } else {
    die('empty cmd');
  }
} else {
  die('no command');
}
```